# Did I get a virus? (Galaxy S4, 5.0.1)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, malware

I was just normally using my S4 when it restarted, and when it turned back on, it said Android is upgrading. The last time I saw this, I was notified of a software update, and I manually clicked install, IIRC. This time, it was sudden and unprecedented. I think this is a virus, though I don't know how I got it.

Comment: Sounds like Android was updating to me, not a virus! Maybe a new auto-update feature from the last software update? I can't imagine a virus creating that prompt.

Comment: Did you get an android with turning cogwheels in its belly and a progress bar (i.e. a system upgrade or fresh system install), or did you just get an "Android is being upgraded" message and and something like "51 apps out of 89 have been optimised"?

Comment: I think it is a virus, because the last time I updated, there was an android (robot, mascot, creature? I don't know) for a few minutes. This time, I just saw a white box saying "Android is being upgraded" It did this in 10 seconds or so then moved on to say "Optimizing app 1 of 1." I do not have only 1 app installed. When I manually updated, it optimized 270 or so apps.

Comment: This means one app (since it said "app 1 of 1") had to be recompiled for some reason. I seriously doubt that it's a virus. Some file had been corrupted, and the kernel panicked, because that file was essential. File corruption shouldn't happen, but nothing is flawless, and it does occasionally. If it doesn't happen again, don't worry. But if it does happen again, and more and more frequently, it might indicate that the internal storage in your phone is starting to fail. Eventually all storage devices do fail. If this is the case, you should look into getting a new phone.

Comment: Oh, ok. I suppose that could happen with a phone of this age. Also, I think that should be posted as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: I added a little to the answer. I don't know if the system automatically notifies you of edits to answers, so I thought I'd better let you know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it only optimised one app, and not all, it means that this app had to be recompiled. It is possible that this app had just been updated, and failed to get compiled at installation, but it's more likely that some file(s) needed by the already compiled app had been corrupted. As your phone rebooted, this app was probably a critical system app, the failure of which caused the kernel to panic (strictly speaking, a panic isn't a crash, but an active decision by the kernel to shut operations down immediately).

Data corruption shouldn't occur on a healthy storage device, but nothing is perfect, and it occasionally does. If this doesn't happen again, you needn't worry, but if it does, it may indicate that the internal storage in your phone is starting to fail. This eventually happens to all storage devicees, flash storage as well as magnetic and optical media. Back up your personal data as often as you can, and consider getting a new phone. If it does not only happen again, but does so more and more frequently, you should definitely get a new phone as soon as possible.

Theoretically it could be a virus that corrupted the file(s), but a virus that infects apps in a way that the apps or the kernel can detect, wouldn't be very cleverly designed, so I seriously doubt that this is the case.